# jshint error: strings must use single quote

Tags: javascript, jshint

How to prevent this error from jslint in one javascript file when the code has to use a quote inside a quote like this:

```
var checkBoxTemplate = '<div class="ngCellText text-center" ng-cell-text ng-class="col.colIndex()" ' +
            'style="height: 100%;vertical-align: middle"> ' +
            '   <span ng-show="COL_FIELD" class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"  style="margin-top: 6px;"/> ' +
            '</div> ';
```

**EDIT:**
Found the culprit. In my .jshintrc file I had this line:

```
 "quotmark": "single"
```

I even found a way to disable it for one file only. You have to add this line at the beginning of the javascript file:

```
/*jshint -W109 */
```

and the error message for this file is disabled.

**EDIT 2**
From the JSHint documentation for quotmark:

Warning This option has been deprecated and will be removed in the next major release of JSHint. JSHint is limiting its scope to issues of code correctness. If you would like to enforce rules relating to code style, check out the JSCS project.

Comment: Plz provide the link to lint tool that you are using. I am not getting any error in my lint.

Comment: no errors [here](http://jshint.com/)

Comment: ... and no errors [here](http://jslint.com/) either if you add a `/*jslint white:true */`. Ditto Rama; what tool is telling you to use a single quote? **What happens if you swap `'` and `"` in your code?**

Comment: Solved it. See my edit above.